# Finding current dynamic IP of a remote computer

Tags: linux, ip, dynamic, dynamic-dns

I need to access a remote computer using VNC.
the computer has a static IP in its network but connects to Internet trough a VPN connection.
How can I find current IP of this computer from my own system (remotely)?
Can something like DynamicDNS help (e.g. `ddclient` && `dnsomatic.com`)?  If Yes; does a free service exists?

Both systems run Linux

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, some sort of dynamic DNS setup would work best.  There are plenty of free dynamic DNS services, or you can run your own with a bit of BIND and nsclient.

Comment: running my own needs a system with static IP as a server; doesn't it? can you suggest me some free services? thanks

Comment: @Snigger: We don't do product recommendations here, for [many very good reasons](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).